# object of type 'NoneType' has no len() when trying to merge two dataframes on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that have two overlapping columns: NumberID and Amount.  My NumberID is not unique enough to do a simple left join on just that column, but when combined with Amount, it is.  I want to be able to merge df2 onto df1 when the values in these two columns are equal, and if not, pass/fill with NaN. I have written the following code so far:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['Number', 'Amount'])
```

but that throws this error: `object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

I have confirmed that there are no null values in either of the two columns in both dataframes.  I do, however, have null values scattered in each df (but in different columns).  Is there a way to ignore NoneType values?  Or is there a better way to accomplish what I want?  I thought about also doing an if statement within df.iterrows, something like:

```
   for rows, index in df1.iterrows:
        if df1[['Number', 'Amount'] = df2[['Number', 'Amount']] 
        then rows(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) 
else pass
```

But my syntax isn't quite right.  Any help?

Comment: Can you post an example of your df1 and df2? That helps in trying to see what goes wrong.

Comment: I also see a lot of problems with your syntax for df1.iterrows. But df.iterrows should't have to be the way to go..,

Comment: ok, I did clean up my syntax a bit for the df.iterrows approach, but still not working.  can't really post the data set.

Answer (score 0):

Not the real solution (difficult to reproduce without some sample data), but at least I think your syntax should be something along these lines:

```
df1_2_list = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows(): #index should be before row and you missed parentheses
    if len(df2[df2['Number', 'Amount'] == row['Number', 'Amount']]) >0: # You should check for the line 'row' instead of matching the whole df1. Here I sliced df2 based on the number and amount in the row from df1. If this is a match, the len(...) should return a length > 0
        df1_2_list.append([row, df2[df2['Number', 'Amount'] == row['Number', 'Amount']]])
    else:
        df1_2_list.append([row])

df1_2 = pd.concat(df1_2_list, names=[df1.colums, df2.columns])
```

Again, this probably doesn't work yet, but will hopefully point you a bit more in the right direction.

But merging should also work. Isn't it possible to just post some rows of the df1 / df2 (can be dummy data if it is sensitive, as long as it correctly represents your data)?

Comment: Thank you for this - I tried it but it threw an error on my columns, curiously enough.  I ended up just combining the two columns into one for both dfs and then just did a single merge on that concatenated.  Inelegant, for sure, but it worked.

Comment: Good that you found something that works. Like I said, merging is always a lot better then using df.iterrows() for this...